# Using a composite estimator with sklearn's cross_validate method, what does the "fit_time" argument include?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning, cross-validation

Using sklearn make_pipeline utility you can create a composite estimator as I have done below (clf). Every time the cross_validate method is called, it first fits the minmax scaler on the kfolds that are not being used for validation, and the transforms the final fold, only then is the model fit.

The cross_validate method returns a value called the "fit_time". Does this fit time take into account the minmax scaling, or does it only time training the "model" (second argument to make_pipeline).

Thanks.

```
#The following clf uses minmax scaling
clf = make_pipeline(preprocessing.MinMaxScaler(), model)

results = cross_validate(clf, Data, labels, cv=kfold,return_train_score=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.html):

> fit_time
>
> ```
> The time for fitting the estimator on the train set for each cv split.
> ```

I would say it only counts the estimator, which should be the model and not the scalling.

But you can test it, if you exclude your scalling in one test run and see if the time is different.